# asp page odbc connection

Tags: asp-classic, odbc

I have an asp page which brings data from DB through ODBC connection, but it's failing. The stored proc is defined in the asp page which brings the data, SP seems to be fine but data is not coming.

Comment: No error is attached; also, please show code that is executing, that causes the error.

Comment: Do you really want to post your passwords on the internet?

Comment: What database are you using?  If it's SQL Server or Access you would probably be better using an OLEDB connection, (unless that's not an option because there are too many instances of your connection string to rewrite throughout your code).  www.connectionstrings.com is a resource I often recommend

Comment: Hello, The previous this is resolved now, I am able to get/fetch documents directly from DB, but now unable to open those pdfs, every time I try a blank window opens up in browser but unable to view or save the pdf files, Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out this issue.Commented out the ODBC section and created a new SQL connection string directly in the asp page-
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open strConn

"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=SERVER\INSTANCE;Database=DBName;UID=***;PWD=**"

Answer (score 0):

Post the error, blur your passwords (hope that box isn't exposed.)

Your error is likely a missing ODBC driver.  Check whether your sites AppPool is running 32 bit or 64 bit, then check the respective ODBC Manager to see if the driver you are using exists on the machine.  If not go download one for whatever database server you are using and install it.

If you have windows 8+ or 2012 Server + on the server, just use the start screen search to find the ODBC managers, can't remember their run commands, and their difficult to find in the UI, I don't even remember where they are.

This commonly happens when people switch their app pool from 32 bit to 64 bit in a server upgrade, or just to run 64 bit.  There are two versions of ODBC drivers, one 32 and one 64 bit.  If you don't have the 64 bit ODBC driver and switch the app pool to 64 bit, your DB access will time out or fail.  ASP commonly has "On Error Resume Next" all over the place, so might be eating the error and showing something generic instead.

Comment: You should probably add to that that you can find the 64 bit odbc manager in control panel.  The 32 bit version is harder to find unless you know where to look - It's at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Hello,
The previous this is resolved now, I am able to get/fetch documents directly from DB, but now unable to open those pdfs, every time I try a blank window opens up in browser but unable to view or save the pdf files, Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: Not being able to see PDF's is likely a client side browser issue, not server side.  If a user does not have a PDF viewer with a browser plugin installed on their machine, then they can't view PDF's in a browser, and there is nothing you can do to code for that server side except to instruct clients to download Adobe Reader or FoxIt PDF Viewer, etc.